# Search list in list written in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have modified a simple search list in list (codes borrowed from another site) but unable to capture all the relevant information.

INPUT FILE :

```
data = [['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['b','d'],['a','b']]
```

I am searching the whole list with a 'b' in it but my algorithm only captures anything ending with a 'b'. I could not capture all 'b' whether it starts in Index(0) or Index(1).

```
data = [['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['b','d'],['a','b']]
search = 'b'
for sublist in data:
    if sublist[1] == search:
        print("Found it!" + str(sublist))
```

Below is the OUTPUT but it is missing ['b','d']. Could someone help please?

```
Found it!['a', 'b']
Found it!['a', 'b']
```

Comment: You are checking `sublist[1] == search`, i.e. if and only if second element of sublist is equal to `search`. Change it to `search in sublist` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 8):

Just use `in` for membership check like,

```
>>> data = [['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['b','d'],['a','b']]
>>> for sub in data:
...   if 'b' in sub:
...     print(sub)
... 
['a', 'b']
['b', 'd']
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. May the force be with you.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
data = [['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['b','d'],['a','b']]
search = 'b'
for sublist in data:
    # Edited this part
    if search in sublist:
        print("Found it!" + str(sublist))
```

Output:

```
Found it!['a', 'b']
Found it!['b', 'd']
Found it!['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working.  It is very clean and clear and well structure.

Comment: Is there any difference if my input data are surrounded by parentheses?

Comment: data = [('a','b'), ('a','c'), ('b','d'),('a','b')]

Comment: No, it will be same, except in the output you will see "Found it!('a', 'b')" instead of "Found it!['a', 'b']".

Comment: What about a tuple? I am always confused with [], {} or () or SET too.

Comment: That will also work. ('a', 'b') is a tuple ['a', 'b'] is a list.

Comment: I have a list of data but could not be matched using your algorithm. Not sure why. I am formatting now and get back to you later.

Comment: Hi Dipen, I could not figure out if it is list or tuple, anyway I could not match. Could you tell me what is wrong with this format of data? Here is the Output:  Sublist : ['REPORT_ID,Stats Area,Suburb,Postcode,LGA Name,Total Units,Total Cas,Total Fats,Total SI,Total MI,Year,Month,Day,Time,Area Speed,Position Type,Horizontal Align,Vertical Align,Other Feat,Road Surface,Moisture Cond,Weather Cond,DayNight,Crash Type,Unit Resp,Entity Code,CSEF Severity,Traffic Ctrls,DUI Involved,Drugs Involved,ACCLOC_X,ACCLOC_Y,UNIQUE_LOC']
 Key : REPORT_ID

Comment: 'Sublist' contains the data and  'Key' contains the search value.